# app-file not running on different mac

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glut

I have created an app-file with Qt. It contains openGL, Qt and c++ code.

My pro file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .


# Input
HEADERS += openglscene.h \
glwidget.h 

QT += opengl

OTHER_FILES +=

RESOURCES += \
    images.qrc

mac: LIBS += -framework GLUT
else:unix|win32: LIBS += -lGLUT

FORMS +=
```

I get the following error message, when trying to run the app-file on a different mac:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded:    /Developer/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/QtOpenGL
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/model.app/Contents/MacOS/model
  Reason: image not found
```

The other macs dont have Qt installed. As it seems I somehow need to include an openGL-framework. How is it possible to do so that other users of my app would be able use it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all your application's dependencies including Qt in the app bundle. qmake doesn't take care of this by itself. Qt comes with a little tool, `macdeployqt`, which might do what you need. A more sophisticated solution is using CMake and [DeployQt4.cmake](https://github.com/mikemcquaid/CMake/blob/deployqt4/Modules/DeployQt4.cmake)